# Multiplying Duration

Tags: google-sheets, statistics

I have a spreadsheet with, in one column a duration express using the following format:`4:36`. 4 minutes and 36 seconds. I would like to multiply it with a number representing the number of views on the video. For instance, the spreadsheet would look like this:

1876|4:36

What shall I put in the next cell to multiply the two, ultimately I would like to have the result in the format: "HH:mm:ss".

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=TEXT(((REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(B1), "^\d+")*60+
 REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(B1), "\d+$"))*A1)/1440/60, "[h]:mm:ss")
```

[image]